# Cloned Gui Frame from ReplicatedStorage is parented in StarterGui, but still not visible

Tags: roblox

I am trying to clone a frame from ReplicatedStorage and parent it to another frame in StarterGui. I expect to see the text in the frame, but cannot. When I manually duplicate the frame in ReplicatedStorage in the editor and drag it to the frame in StarterGui, it works fine, and I see can see the text. There are no errors or warnings. When I run the script and the updateDisplay function is called, I can see and move the edges of the frames from ReplicatedStorage but not the text.

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local StarterGui = game:GetService("StarterGui")

local updateResourceDisplay = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("UpdateResourceDisplay")

local function updateDisplay(resources)
    for key, value in pairs(resources) do
        local newResource = ReplicatedStorage.ResourceTemplate:Clone()
        newResource.Parent = StarterGui.ScreenGui.LeftFrame.Frame
    end
end

updateResourceDisplay.OnClientEvent:Connect(updateDisplay)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that StarterGui is only for the... start. If you want to change the player's gui at runtime, that's done with PlayerGui not StarterGui. Changing the second line to the following code and replacing the reference from StarterGui to PlayerGui worked:

```
local PlayerGui = game:GetService('Players').LocalPlayer:WaitForChild('PlayerGui')
```